# User with permissions can't access file in shared folder

Tags: hard-drive, permissions, windows-server-2003

I have a user in my network, he has permission to read, write and modify on a shared folder but when he tried to open file in the shared folder he can't... The operating system is Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 2):

To have access to a file/folder through a share, the user must have the appropriate share permissions but also the appropriate NTFS permissions (the most restrictive permissions apply). These concepts are explained in [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178.aspx)
Microsoft Technet article.

The point is your user probably does not have the required NTFS permissions on the folder he needs to access.